# How do you make a Handler stop taking input until prompted in Android?

Tags: android, handler

I have a Handler as defined below. What I want is to be able to trigger this Handler to stop working and maybe retrigger it to work with a button press. I am currently using a variable `isScrubbing` to stop the operations from happening. What I would optimally like is to do a `mUpdateTimeTask.sleep()`

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(isScrubbing == 0) {
            .
            .
            .
        }
        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no such method like sleep. Remember that the Handler posts Runnables to a queue from where the UI Thread takes task to execute. A possibile implementation of what you want could be:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    private boolean exit;

    public void run() {
       if (exit) {
          return;
       }
       // do what you have to do
       mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }

    public void start() {
       exit = false;
       mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }    

   public void stop() {
      exit = true;
      mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
   }
}
```

just instantiate it once, and call the method `start()` to post the first time (the run method re-posts itself), and `stop()` to exit. The boolean is not necessary, `mHandler.removeCallbacks(this)` is already enough. Another implementation

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    private boolean exit;

    public void run() {
       if (exit) {
          // do your clean up work
          mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
          return;
       }
       // do what you have to do
       mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }

    public void start() {
       exit = false;
       mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }    

   public void stop() {
      exit = true;
   }
}
```